# Python3: Should characters in string be treated as Int, Float, or String?

Tags: python-3.x, types, type-conversion

## Goal:

(In Python 3.6)

Determine if the string passed to the function should be interpreted as an Int, Float or String.
Hopefully (with a builtin Python functions) without needed to write my own function which walks chars in Python.

Basically, like the C `atoi()` and `atoll()` functions, if the entire buffer is successfully read.

### Should mark as Int:

- "-1234"
- "1234"
- "+1234"

### Should mark as Float:

- "-1.234"
- "1.234"
- "+1.234"

### Should mark as string:

- "972-727-9857"
- "1_2345"
- "asdf"

## Tried:

### Using casts:

```
def find_type(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return int
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        float(s)
        return float
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return str
```

^ the above has the drawback:

- "1_234" -> int(1234)

### Using AST

```
import ast

def find_type(s):
    obj_type = ast.literal_eval(s)
    if isinstance(obj_type, float):
        return float
    if isinstance(obj_type, int):
        return int
    return str
```

^ this also has issues with:

- "123_123" -> int(123123)
- "123-123-123" -> int(-123)

---

### Question

Am I just doomed to write my own function which walks chars? ... I am about to just write this in C...

[How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

^ I found the above, but it doesn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: Well, you can easily check `if '_' in s: return str` in the first approach as an edge case

Comment: How about "1.23E-1", which represents 0.123 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrmm... after posting this question, I thought of this:

### With Regex:

```
import re
int_regex = re.compile(r'^(-|\+)?[0-9]+$')
float_regex = re.compile(r'^(-|\+)?([0-9]+)?\.[0-9]+$')

def find_type(s):
    if re.match(int_regex, s):
        return int
    if re.match(float_regex, s):
        return float
    return str
```

I guess this is probably the only/best way.

Comment: What about ".1" or "1." or "1e-1"?

Comment: Good point about the ".1" and "1." ... I think in my use case it is fine to not support "1e-1" ...

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the underscore:

```
def find_type(s):
    if '_' in s:
        return str
    for typ in (int,float):
        try:
            typ(s)
            return typ
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return str

trials = '-1234','1234','+1234','-1.234','1.234','+1.234','972-727-9857','1_2345','asdf'

for trial in trials:
    print(trial,find_type(trial))
```

Output:

```
-1234 <class 'int'>
1234 <class 'int'>
+1234 <class 'int'>
-1.234 <class 'float'>
1.234 <class 'float'>
+1.234 <class 'float'>
972-727-9857 <class 'str'>
1_2345 <class 'str'>
asdf <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Nice pattern on the loop which only requires one try/except ...